# Posting a data using react-query only when clicking a button, returns the value of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I want to take the response and send it to another page when I press a button and submit the form data preferably using react-query.

I have three inputs on the form page: username, email, and password. I want to submit that to the /auth/register router which will send me the user's response which contains the email and ID. Then I want to redirect and send that data to the verify-account page.

```
'use client'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import usePost from '../hooks/usePost'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Button from '@/components/pages/Button'
import Axios from '@/components/lib/axios/Axios'


export default function Form({ formPage }: { formPage: string }) {
  const axios = new Axios()
  const router = useRouter()
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    username: '',
  })

  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  const content = usePost({endpoint: `${formPage.toLowerCase()}`,formData: formData})


  const onSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    content.refetch()
    setFormData({ email: '', password: '', username: '' })
    // data.status === 200 && (formPage === 'Login' ? router.push('/dashboard') : router.push('/verify-account'))  
  }
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {formPage === 'Register' && (
          <div className='mx-5 my-10 w-full flex flex-col items-start'>
            <input
              type='text'
              name='username'
              id='username'
              placeholder='Username'
              className='w-full rounded-md p-2 input input-bordered'
              onChange={onChange}
              value={formData['username']}
            />
          </div>
        )}
        <div className='mx-5 my-10 w-full flex flex-col items-start'>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='email'
            id='email'
            placeholder='Email'
            className='w-full rounded-md p-2 input input-bordered'
            onChange={onChange}
            value={formData['email']}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='m-5 w-full flex flex-col items-start'>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='password'
            id='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            className='w-full rounded-md p-2 input input-bordered'
            onChange={onChange}
            value={formData['password']}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={formPage === 'Login' ? 'w-full m-5 flex justify-between' : 'w-full m-5 flex justify-center'}>
          <Link href={formPage === 'Login'? '/register' : '/login'} className='text-md text-green-500'>
            {formPage === 'Login'? 'Create Account' : 'Already have an account'}
          </Link>
          {formPage === 'Login' && (
            <Link href='/login' className='text-md text-green-500'>
              Forgot Password?
            </Link>
          )}
        </div>
        <Button buttonText={formPage} />
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

I am using react-query to try and achieve that. I have made a custom hook "usePost" that uses the query to send the request to the server and get response.

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import Axios from "../lib/axios/Axios"

export default function usePost({endpoint, formData}: {endpoint:string, formData: any}){
    const axios = new Axios()
    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ["posts"],
        queryFn: async () => {
            console.log( endpoint, formData)
            return await axios.post(`/auth/${endpoint}`, formData)
        },
        enabled: false,
    })
}
```

I only want the request to be sent when the form is filled and being submitted, so I have put the property of enabled to false. Now, the problem occurs when I press the button. The initial state of the query will be pending. However, it still fulfills the request but in doing so the returned value becomes undefined.

So, how can I make that the query returns the value on the first click and I send the return value to verify-account page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to use Reactive stuff (anything that starts with "use") is when you want that thing to change based on state.  If you want something to change based on a user action like clicking a button, you shouldn't use a React hook for that.  The logic you're describing should instead be in an event handler -- `onSubmit()` in this case.

If you want to update your React Query cache from the event handler in addition to sending the network request, you can do that with the [queryClient.setQueryData](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/reference/QueryClient#queryclientsetquerydata) function directly rather than one of the useQuery hooks.